# avoid double quotes from array

Tags: javascript

iam getting the output like this

```
["/Vegetables/","/Fruits/"]
```

but i want like this `[/Vegetables/,/Fruits/]`

here is my code

```
    var varieties=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < catagories.length; i++) {
    // actually catagories output is like this ["Vegetables","Fruits"]
    //here iam adding slashes for my requirement.

     var eg1 = "/"+catagories[i]+"/";
     var eg2= eg1.replace(/"/g, "");
    varieties.push(eg2);    
    }
console.log(JSON.stringify(varieties));
```

after using "replace" also still iam getting output like   `["/Vegetables/","/Fruits/"]`

please help me to get the output like `[/Vegetables/,/Fruits/]`

Comment: It's not valid JSON without the quotes.

Comment: You simply **can't**. JSON always uses double quotes for string values.

Comment: You have the correct output

Comment: Not only is it not valid JSON, it's not valid JS either... a string will have quotes around it, no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, you cannot have a string without quotes. "/Vegetables/" is a valid string but /Vegetables is an error as its neither a variable name nor string.

Your expected output is a invalid JS Array. In order to get an output [/Vegetables,/Fruits], try using replace on the output of Stringify.
Not sure why you have such a requirement of removing "" but below snippet should fulfil your requirements.

```
var catagories = ["Vegetables","Fruits"];
var eg1 = JSON.stringify(catagories); 
var eg2= eg1.replace(/"/g, "/");
console.log(eg2);
```

> Output: [/Vegetables/,/Fruits/]

Comment: You could also mention that `JSON.stringify` adds quotes around all strings.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks for the suggestion. Yes you are correct. Stringify converts the entire JSON structure to a string by adding quotes to non-string items.